# How CEFSharp Manually Disables JavaScript？

Tags: c#, cefsharp

CEFSharp CPU Usage is too high, I want to reduce CPU usage, One solution is disable some browser page javascript. but i have not idea to disable it. how i can do?

Comment: just i want that do. do you have any solution??

Comment: http://cefsharp.github.io/api/67.0.0/html/P_CefSharp_BrowserSettings_Javascript.htm

Comment: var browser=...;
browser.BrowserSettings.Javascript = CefSharp.CefState.Disabled;
it's not work

Comment: Please be patient, it hasn't even been 24hrs. There is no need to cross post on `GitHub` like you did opening https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2619. I have many people asking me questions and it takes time to answer them all.

Comment: Using `71.0.0-pre01` and loading https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/is-javascript-enabled reports javascript is disabled. You will need to edit your post and include details if you require further assistance, the code sample you have provided is too brief.